# Using Selenium "find_elements_by_class_name" to retrieve data from website

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, pycharm

I'm trying my hand at some python code, and am having a hell of a time with Selenium.  Any help you could offer would be super appreciated.  Long story short, I'm trying to pull the average rating of a given movie from Letterboxd.com.  For example:

https://letterboxd.com/film/the-dark-knight/

The value I'm looking for is the average rating to 2 decimal places, which you can see if you mouseover the rating that's displayed on the page:

[Average Rating 4.43 displayed on mousover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDlhk.png)

In this case, the average rating is 4.43, and that's the number I'm trying to retrieve.

So far, I've managed to successfully grab the 1 decimal place version using `driver.find_elements_by_class_name('average-rating')`
In this case, that returns "4.4".  But I need "4.43."

I can see the correct value in the developer tools.  It appears twice.  Once here:

```
<span class="average-rating" itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
<a href="/film/the-dark-knight/ratings/" class="tooltip display-rating -highlight" data-original-title="Weighted average of 4.43 based on 444,083&nbsp;ratings">4.4</a>
```

And again in what appears to be metadata:

```
<meta name="twitter:data2" content="4.43 out of 5">
```

Any suggestions on how I can grab that value correctly?  Thanks so much!

Cheers,
Ari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the code and let me know if you don't understand anything. To Hover over Main Rating you should use actionchains.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://letterboxd.com/film/the-dark-knight/")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

time.sleep(10)
Main_Rating = driver.find_element_by_class_name('average-rating')
print("Main Rating is :- " + Main_Rating.text)

time.sleep(5)
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(Main_Rating).perform()

More_Rating_info = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="twipsy-inner"]').text
More_Message = More_Rating_info.split()

print("More Rating :- " + More_Message[3])
```

Note - If this resolves your problem then please mark it as answer.

Comment: Thank you!  That works beautifully!  One question: why the "time.sleep" for a total of 15 seconds?  As I'm going to be running this several times in a loop, that's ... a lot.  I tried cutting that down to .25 seconds each, and it seems to work fine.  But I was just curious: is there a reason for the "sleep" functions?

Comment: You can put implicit wait and remove all the `time.sleep()`

`driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

Answer (score 1):

There is another way you might wanna think of using to get the `rating` along with the counting of `users` voted for that rating. Given that they all are available in the page source within some script tag.

```
import re
import json
import requests

URL = 'https://letterboxd.com/film/the-dark-knight/'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36'
    r = s.get(URL)
    data = json.loads(re.findall(r"CDATA[^{]+(.*)",r.text)[0])
    rating = data['aggregateRating']['ratingValue']
    user_voted = data['aggregateRating']['ratingCount']
    print(rating,user_voted)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code using [beautiful soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/):

Benefit of using Beautiful soup and requests:

1. Fast in terms of getting result.
2. Less error.
3. More accessibility to html tags.

   ```
    import requests
    from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
    requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

    def extract_avg_rating():

    movie_name = 'the-dark-knight'
    url = 'https://letterboxd.com/film/' + movie_name
    session = requests.Session()
    url_response = session.get(url,verify=False)
    soup = bs(url_response.text, 'html.parser')
    extracted_meta = soup.find_all('meta')[19]
    extracted_rating = extracted_meta.attrs['content'].split(' ')[0]
    print('Movie ' + movie_name + ' rating ' + extracted_rating)

    extract_avg_rating()
   ```

In the above code movie_name parameter you can put any film name for ex: **lucky-grandma** and it will give you the accurate rating. Code is dynamic and help you in extracting other movies ratings and other information despite of only one thing as per your requirement.